# How to extract observational data from RDA or RDS files in Bayesian Network Repository?

Tags: r, bayesian-networks

I'm using Bayesian Network Repository (http://www.bnlearn.com/bnrepository/gaussian-medium.html#ecoli70) to obtain several datasets.

To learn a Bayesian network structure, I need the observational data from each dataset. I'm not sure if Bayesian Network Repository includes this information or not.

If it does, my question is how I can extract observational data from the datasets given in Bayesian Network Repository dataset. The observational data is in the form of a matrix of size n by p where n is the number of samples and p is the number of random variables.

Comment: what you can do is draw a sample of specified size from a given BN --- see `bnlearn::rbn`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `ecoli` dataset, which can be found in the `GeneNet` package:

```
install.packages("GeneNet")
data(ecoli, package="GeneNet")
```

Comment: Thanks. This actually helped me a lot. How about if I want to get observational data of MAGIC-NIAB dataset?

Comment: Not sure.  You could check the `bnlearn` package, which your link references:  `install.packages("bnlearn"); data(package="bnlearn")`.

Comment: It does not have those data, unfortunately.